# Jquery - Change table cell values based on table row class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table displays opening hours for various locations and looks somewhat like the following structure;

```
<table class="tblServices">
 <tbody>
   <tr class="name loc1">
    <td class="name">loc1</td>
    <td class=""tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="name loc2">
    <td class="name">loc1</td>
    <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to be able to do is change the value of all table cells with the class "tcDayTimes" within the row the class "loc2", I have gotten close with the following jquery but its replacing the values for every cell with that class no matter what table row its in.

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.tblServices > tbody > tr.loc2').each(
        $('td.tcDayTimes').html("24 hours")
```

Can some provide some advice as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that's how you use `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your html, but otherwise...

```
$('.tblServices > tbody > tr.loc2').each(function(){
  $('td.tcDayTimes', this).html("24 hours")
});
```

Where `this` is the tr you are iterating over.  The second argument to the `$()` is the context.

OR

```
$('.tblServices > tbody > tr.loc2 td.tcDayTimes').html("24 hours");
```

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery

You were close. In your selector, you need to add `> .tcDayTimes`, which stores the items into a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Then use `.html()` to change the html of all those elements.

```js
$(".tblServices > tbody > .loc2 > .tcDayTimes").html("24 hours");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblServices">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="name loc1">
      <td class="name">loc1</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="name loc2">
      <td class="name ">loc1</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Vanilla Javascript

You can also use the following method to do this in vanilla javascript. This basically uses [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the values you wanted and store them into a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (like an array). Then you can use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set the html of those elements.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tblServices > tbody > .loc2 > .tcDayTimes");

elements.forEach(e => {
  e.innerHTML = "24 hours";
});
```

```html
<table class="tblServices">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="name loc1">
      <td class="name">loc1</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="name loc2">
      <td class="name ">loc1</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
      <td class="tcDayTimes">9-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**You dont need the `>`. You can just have `.tblServices tbody .loc2 .tcDayTimes`, but it makes it look neater, and I would keep it there if I were you.**

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is helpful